# Is it possible with javascript to actually trigger with onmouseover all children elements' functions by doing only onmouseover on their parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this onmouseover function to bring one random different chemical element symbol to child span elements at each side of my 3 lines nested on on each of my parent divs.

```
const randomSymbols = [
"Ac","Ag","Al","Am","Ar","As","At","Au","B","Ba","Be","Bh","Bi","Bk","Br","C","Ca","Cd","Ce",
"Cf","Cl","Cm","Cn","Co","Cr","Cs","Cu","Db","Ds","Dy","Er","Es","Eu","F","Fe","Fl","Fm","Fr",
"Ga","Gd","Ge","H","He","Hf","Hg","Ho","Hs","I","In","Ir","K","Kr","La","Li","Lr","Lu","Lv",
"Mc","Md","Mg","Mn","Mo","Mt","N","Na","Nb","Nd","Ne","Nh","Ni","No","Np","O","Og","Os","P",
"Pa","Pb","Pd","Pm","Po","Pr","Pt","Pu","Ra","Rb","Re","Rf","Rg","Rh","Rn","Ru","S","Sb","Sc",
"Se","Sg","Si","Sm","Sn","Sr","Ta","Tb","Tc","Te","Th","Ti","Tl","Tm","Ts","U","V","W","Xe",
"Y","Yb","Zn","Zr",
]

const allsymbols = document.querySelectorAll(".mySymbols");

for(let symbol of allsymbols) {
    symbol.onmouseenter = function() {
       var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (randomSymbols.length))
       this.innerText = randomSymbols[randomNum]
    } 
}
```

Once I get those different random chemical element symbols, I use a different function to copy the whole parent div with the 6 new random chemical symbols, one for each child span element, by clicking once the parent div. Happily the copy function to copy the whole div works fine so it is not my problem, and you can see it on the JSFiddle bellow.

I started this with only 10 parent divs and it was easy to trigger this function on each of the 6 child span elements for each parent div, but now it is a nightmare to keep moving the mouse over 6 different areas on each of 900 divs.

For this reason I've been trying to find a way to trigger all 6 child elements onmouseover function, by only doing onmouseover or onmouseenter on the parent div, but every possible function I've found only edits each child element style, and none actually triggers their functions.

My hope is to find some help by asking this question to our community here.

However, if it is not possible to do this through an onmouseover or onmouseenter trigger on the parent div, I would like to ask if there is any way to bring random content for each of the 6 child span elements probably by clicking on each of the parent divs, from a different approach, of course, as I'm totally open to a complete different function, if necessary.

To make my question more clear, I created this [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rx65m/L8s5jceo/3/)
Please take a look to it, so you can understand easily my issue, and perhaps see a solution for it as well.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [.trigger(}](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)?  `$(".mySymbols").trigger("mouseenter")` - not sure that's a good idea though.

Comment: There's a lot of words there - what ***exactly*** is the goal?

Comment: Thanks you  @freedomn-m do you mind to let me know me how to use that?

Comment: @Rory-McCrossan Excatly how to actually trigger all children elements with onmouseover functions by doing only onmouseover on their parent div?

Comment: Updated fiddle including the sample from comment above: https://jsfiddle.net/p1d6nraL/  Change where you hover to change how it works (ie from `.allSymbols` to `.main`.   Note: you've tagged [tag:jquery] but you weren't using it.

Comment: @freedomn-m That is absolutely fantastic! Thank you very much!

Comment: If you want it per box, then you also need to make sure you stopPropagation as events bubble up - so the parent element triggering a child element with the trigger that parent element again as the child element's event bubbles up to the parent.  https://jsfiddle.net/p1d6nraL/1/

Comment: Thank you very much @freedomn-m I think both options are really good. I'll try both to see which one is more comfortable.
I would like to mark your answers as the best, but I don't know if what I marked so far is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can also assign to your divs a 'onmouseenter' function that will dispatch a 'mouseenter' event to all the child spans of the current div:

```
const mouseEnterEvent = new Event("mouseenter"); // Store the event

function triggerMouseEnterOnChildSpans(className) {
  document.querySelectorAll(`.${className} > span`) // Select spans whose parent use 'className'
    .forEach(childSpan => childSpan.dispatchEvent(mouseEnterEvent));
}

document.querySelectorAll("[class^='div']") // Select elements with class starting by 'div'
  .forEach(div => div.onmouseenter = () => triggerMouseEnterOnChildSpans(div.className));
```

Bonus: No jQuery involved :)

Comment: Thank you Thomas Zimmermann! This looks great as well. I'm trying this one too, to see which one is more comfortable.